# Beanshell Assertion

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Could you help me with this Beanshell Assertion code:

I need to add 3 AND conditions & in the 3rd AND condition I need to add OR condition as well and I have tried the following code and I am getting the error 
"BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String Response1 = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); String Response2 = prev.getRe . . . '' : Operator: '"||"' inappropriate for objects
"

Please click on the link to view the code I tried:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text within your question. That way people can copy and paste it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your or condition should be between boolean expressions. So end your line with

```
  &&  (Response3.contains("Value4") || Response3.contains("Value5"))
```

Notice also that the convention for Java variables is starting with a lowerCase character as `response3`